# Vue3 Component "OnMounted" Refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, components, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 Dynamic Component wrapped in `<keep-alive>` that essentially adds navigation within a PrimeVue `<Dialog>`, and is populated by an object:

```
const component = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Test'
    props: {
        ...
    }
  },
  ...
]

<keep-alive>
  <component :is="component.name" :key="component.id" :props="component.props" />
</keep-alive>
```

on one of the pages, there is an `onMounted` function that activates a search when the page is active, however, the user can also navigate back and forth to other pages; after they initially hit the "Search Page", and then try to navigate back, `onMounted` doesn't initiate the search a second time, which is what is needed.

I figured that having a `key` within `<component>` would do the trick for re-rendering, but it didn't seem to, so how should I go about getting the "Search Page" to re-render when navigated?

(For reference, the `<Dialog>` navigation occurs by an `emit` that just increments the `<component :is>` object key).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onMounted** will not trigger when visit the same page on the **second** time.
you can `activates`  with  **onActivated**.

solution1 - move the page out of keep-alive

solution2 - using onActivated